# Convert null string to ""

Tags: java, null

If I have

```
String a = null;
System.out.println(a);
```

I'll get

`null`

Is there an elegant way to change this an empty string?

I could do:

```
if (a == null){
a="";
}
```

The context is that I'll be producing a string of the form:

`String myString = a + "\n" + b + "\n" + c;`

But I'm wondering if there's a nicer solution.

Comment: Could you not just say `String a = "" `? The String would drop its pointer at null, and then point to an empty string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Apache commons lang3](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#defaultString(java.lang.String)) has a function that will do this.

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;

a = null;
System.out.println(StringUtils.defaultString(a));
```

Answer (score 13):

You could try it like this using the [ternary operator](http://java.about.com/od/t/g/ternaryoperator.htm).

```
System.out.println(a == null ? "" : a);
```

Alernatively, you can use the Commons Lang3 function [`defaultString()`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#defaultString(java.lang.String)) as suggested by chrylis,

```
System.out.println(StringUtils.defaultString(a));
```

Answer (score 6):

I would factor out a utility method that captures the intention, which improves readability and allows easy reuse:

```
public static String blankIfNull(String s) {
    return s == null ? "" : s;
}
```

Then use that when needed:

```
System.out.println(blankIfNull(a));
```

Comment: Yeah, that's the best solution I've got so far.

Comment: I'm pretty sure Commons Lang has this already.

Comment: @chrylis If so, post the function.

Comment: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#defaultString(java.lang.String)

Comment: Actually, Java [has this already](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#toString-java.lang.Object-java.lang.String-):  `Objects.toString(s, "")`

Answer (score 2):

You could write a varargs method

```
public static String concat(String... arr) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (String s : arr)
        if (s != null)
            sb.append(s);
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Then you can do

```
String myString = concat(a, "\n", b, "\n", c);
```